# Suggestions but no autompletion

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm working with the integrated terminal in visual studio code. I'm using powershell 7.
Currentyl im experience a strange behavior. While im using powershell in vscode the app offers me suggestions to speed up my developement, which is great

When i'm using tab key to accept the suggestion it does not add the suggested part, but uses the classy autocompletion feature.

Example:

i type: terra  -> it suggests me terra*form init*

but when i push tab it puts terraform.exe in the line.

When im using the right arrow it works as expected but this is not very intutiv to me.

I've added

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource None
```

but this disabled the suggestions and not the autocompletion.

Any ideaas how i could set tab to use the suggestions and not the autocompletion?